# Making linked list more generic

Tags: c, list, generics, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

Could somebody help me understand void pointers using a linked list.

I have:

```
struct listNode
{
    int nodeValue;
    struct listNode * next;
};

typedef struct listNode listNode;
```

Which only works with ints. If I change the int nodeValue to void *nodeValue, how would I send values into my linked list using the void pointer instead?

For instance, I had an add to front function:

```
void addFront(listNode *L, int number);
```

which takes a listNode and a number.

If it was a void* pointer, would I just change the signature to:

```
void addFront(listNode *L, void* value);
```

In my main function using ints I have something like:

```
int main(void)
{   
    listNode *list;
    list = createList();

    for (int x = 0;x < 8;x++)
    {
        addFront(list,x);

    }

    return(0);
}
```

where createList is defined as:

```
listNode *createList()
{
    listNode *anyNode;
    anyNode = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    anyNode->next = NULL;
    return anyNode;
}

listNode *initNode(int number)
{
    listNode *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNode->nodeValue = number;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return(newNode);
}
```

To make the list more generic, how could I pass integers using a void* instead of declaring an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this kind of generic behavior comes at the price of large overhead: in order to save an `int` on a list you would need to extend its scope by allocating an `int` dynamically:

```
listNode *initNode(int number)
{
    listNode *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNode->nodeValue = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(newNode->nodeValue) = number;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return(newNode);
}
```

This increases memory requirements many times, because `malloc(sizeof(int));` typically allocates at least a 16-byte block.

Answer (score 0):

One way to store either ints or pointers would be by making nodeValue into a union type.  Note that to avoid undefined behavior, your calling code would need to be consistent (i.e. if you add ints into the linked list, you shouldn't try to later access them as pointers, or vice-versa).

```
union intOrPointer
{
    int intValue;
    void * pointerValue;
};

struct listNode
{
    union intOrPointer nodeValue;
    struct listNode * next;
};

typedef struct listNode listNode;

listNode *initNode(int number)
{
    listNode *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
    newNode->nodeValue.intValue = number;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return(newNode);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution is using 0-size array into listNode declaration.
For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct listNode
{
  struct listNode *next;
  int nodeValue[0];
};

struct listNode *addFront(struct listNode **head, void *data, size_t size)
{
  struct listNode *new_node = calloc(sizeof(struct listNode) + size, 1);
  if(!new_node)
    return NULL;
  new_node->next = *head;
  *head = new_node->next;
  memcpy(new_node->nodeValue, data, size);
}

void addInt2Front(struct listNode **head, int value)
{
  addFront(head, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int main(void)
{
  struct listNode *head = NULL;
  addInt2Front(&head, 5);
}
```

It is reduces overhead from two allocations because memory for nodeValue allocates with listNode block by one calloc() call.

Comment: Sorry, my addFront need return new_node. 
I am forgot write it into code.